# How to easily create a javascript 2D dictionary where key order does not matter?

Tags: javascript, object, dictionary

I was just wondering if there was away to create a Javascript dictionary where key order does not matter (without having to write an entire class for it myself). Here is an example

```
      | Val A | Val B
Val A | ---   |  1
Val B | 1     | --------
```

A simpler way of stating this, I want an object that has the following property.

```
obj['A']['B'] == obj['B']['A']
```

Is there an easy way to construct an object that enforces this property? Or would I have to code up the constraint myself? I am hoping there might be some trickery with references or something to enforce this behavior.

Comment: What if 'A' happens to be equal to 'B'?

Comment: From what domain are `A` and `B`? Are they always strings?

Comment: They are always guaranteed to be the same type. In this case, yes they are a string.

Comment: In what way is this independence of order necessary?

Comment: Let's take a classic example of distances between two points. Point A and Point B. The distance from Point A to Point B is guaranteed to be equal to the distance from Point B to Point A. It would be really nice if the get parameters worked in either order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your keys comparable, you can write small wrapper around standard dictionary, which will sort keys to specific order before accessing collection.

```
var dictionary = {
    storage: {},
    get: function (a, b){
        if (a > b) {
            let x = b;
            b = a;
            a = x;
        }
        return this.storage[a][b];
    },
    put: function (a, b, value){
        if (a > b){
            let x = b;
            b = a;
            a = x;
        }
        if (typeof this.storage[a] !== "object")
            this.storage[a] = {};
        this.storage[a][b] = value;
    }
}

dictionary.put('A', 'B', 80);
dictionary.put('B', 'C', 100);
dictionary.put('A', 'C', 36);

console.log(dictionary.get('B', 'A'));      //Prints 80
console.log(dictionary.get('C', 'B'));      //Prints 100
console.log(dictionary.get('A', 'C'));      //Prints 36
```

Example could be improved (or not) by storing elements in `dictionary` itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to construct an object that enforces this property?

No, you can't (easily) make an ordinary object (that is accessed as `dict[A][B]`) enforce this.

> Or would I have to code up the constraint myself?

Yes, that's probably the better approach. Write a simple class for your multidimensional dictionary that has getters and setters with multiple arguments (i.e. `dict.get(A, B)`), and then internally compare `A` with `B` to e.g. always put the smaller one first, so that passing in `A, B` and `B, A` end up equivalent. With the keys ordered, access a usual nested dictionary.

Comment: What about an un-ordinary object? I am just need it for a dictionary, not necessarily an ordinary object.

Comment: @Skylion: Do you really need the `dict[A][B]` syntax or could it also be `dict.get(A, B)`? The latter will be much easier.

Comment: Either way would work. Regardless, I found an easier means to parse and structure the data so if you could provide and example such as that, I would accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go visually 2D symmetric object

```js
var size = 5;
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var array = []; // init empty array

for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
 var row = document.createElement('div');
  row.setAttribute('class', 'row');
  
  array[i] = []; // create empty row to fill with column
  
  table.appendChild(row);
 for(j = 0; j < size; j++) {
   var column = document.createElement('div');
    column.innerText = i + "." + j;
   column.setAttribute('class', 'column');
    row.appendChild(column);
    var col_value = document.createElement('div');
   col_value.setAttribute('class', 'col-value');
    col_value.innerText = (j+i);
    column.appendChild(col_value);
      
    array[i][j] = i+j; // apply value for each column;
  }

}

console.log(array); // print to console
```

```css
.column {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 9px;
}
.col-value {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is very useful for someone I am sure, but I was referring to a dictionary. Not a visualization. Thanks though!

Comment: I've updated answer. Also added array in which array[0][3] == array[3][0] return true.